# typedef defenition error when I use cygwin gcc

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

It is my first experience with cygwin gcc, before that I used it on linux. 
I faced a problem solution for which I failed to find in net.

I want to compile C source file and have included this source

```
// Value type defenitions
// --- chars --- //
typedef unsigned char UChar;
typedef char Char;
// --- short int --- //
typedef unsigned short UShort;
typedef short  Short;
// --- int --- //
typedef unsigned int UInt;
typedef int Int;
// --- long int --- //
typedef long  Long;                             // 32 bits length
typedef unsigned long  ULong;                   // unsigned 32 bits length
// --- long long int --- //
typedef unsigned long long  UBig;               // 64-bit length unsigned 
typedef long long Big;                          // 64-bit length
// --- decimals --- //
typedef float Float;
typedef double Double;
typedef long double Triple;    // 80-bit length. Actual   properties unspecified.
```

and have got this error

```
Include/null.h:6: error: redefinition of typedef 'UChar'
Include/null.h:6: error: previous declaration of 'UChar' was here
Include/null.h:7: error: redefinition of typedef 'Char'
Include/null.h:7: error: previous declaration of 'Char' was here
Include/null.h:9: error: redefinition of typedef 'UShort'
Include/null.h:9: error: previous declaration of 'UShort' was here
and so on...
```

---

Thank you for help!

Comment: Looks like you need include guards.

Comment: Include guards would probably solve your immediate problem. But why do you need those typedefs in the first place? If `Char` will always refer to the predefined type `char`, adding a second name doesn't buy you anything; just refer to `char` directly. If it can ever be something else, `Char` is a misleading name. (Likewise for `Int`, `UChar`, etc.) If I see a reference to something called `Int`, I'll have two questions: what does `Int` mean, and why not just use `int`? I see no good answer to the latter.

Comment: I think the meaning of the defenitions aren't so important in that case, I just wanted to know an anwser for my silly question. But, even so thank you for the anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have included the same header, where you have typedef'edthese, more than once. Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to avoid multiple inclusion.